# How to convert to nested type

Tags: go

I've defined the two types

```
type zFrame []byte
type zMsg []zFrame
```

and I have the variable

```
var message [][]byte
```

. Go compiler is telling me

```
cannot use msg (type [][]byte) as type zMsg in function argument
```

when I try to compile

```
myZMsg := zMsg(message)
```

. Changing to

```
type zMsg [][]byte
```

makes things compile, but I like the first solution better. Is there an easy way for me to convert from `[][]byte` to `zMsg` for that case?

Comment: You can do the conversion with `unsafe`, but I'm not sure if it's possible to do it otherwise.

Comment: Why not `var message zMsg`? That's the type you are working with in the first place just stick with it.

Comment: Jeremy: Because [][]byte is returned to me from an external library (ZeroMQ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to do the conversion yourself. For example,

```
package main

type zFrame []byte
type zMsg []zFrame

func main() {
    var message [][]byte
    myZMsg := make(zMsg, len(message))
    for i := range message {
        myZMsg[i] = zFrame(message[i])
    }
}
```